# How to calculate sums of squares in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression, data-science

First, is the formula `TSS = ESS + RSS` always correct? Even for an exponential model? If it is, I just do not understand where am I wrong.

I have 2 arrays of x and y values, where y depends on x.

```py
x = np.array([1.5, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, 3.2, 3.4, 3.6, 3.7, 4.0, 4.5, 5.1, 5.6])
y = np.array([0.6, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.45, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8, 1.9, 1.95, 2.1, 2.2])
```

I have a function that determines coefficients a and b and returns an equation of linear regression (or just a and b if needed)

```py
def Linear(x, y, getAB = False):
    AVG_X = np.average(x)
    AVG_Y = np.average(y)
    DISP_X = np.var(x)
    DISP_Y = np.var(y)
    STD_X = np.std(x)
    STD_Y = np.std(y)

    AVG_prod = np.average(x*y)
    cov = AVG_prod - (AVG_X*AVG_Y)

    b = cov/DISP_X
    a = AVG_Y - b*AVG_X

    if getAB:
        return a, b

    return lambda X: a + b*X
```

I have a function that determines coefficients a and b and returns an equation of EXPONENTIAL regression

```py
def Exponential(x, y, getAB = False):
    LOG_Y_array = [math.log(value) for value in y]

    A, B = Linear(x, LOG_Y_array, getAB = True)

    a = math.exp(A)
    b = math.exp(B)

    if getAB:
        return a, b

    return lambda X: a * (b**X)
```

I created the array of calculated y values based of exponential model

```py
Exponential_Prediction = Exponential(x, y)
Exponential_Prediction_y = [Exponential_Prediction(value) for value in x]
```

And finally, that is how I calculate TSS, ESS and RSS

```py
TSS = np.sum((y - np.average(y))**2)
ESS_Exp = np.sum((Exponential_Prediction_y - np.average(y))**2)
RSS_Exp = np.sum((y-Exponential_Prediction_y)**2)
```

That is all pretty clear, except the output of this

```py
print(str(TSS) + " = " + str(ESS_Exp) + " + " + str(RSS_Exp))
```

is 2.18166666667 = 2.75523753042 + 0.432362713806

I do not understand how ESS could be more than TSS

Comment: Wikipedia says that TSS = ESS + RSS only under certain conditions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_sum_of_squares

Comment: @Vince W I suppose in this case the equation should work. Exponential model like that can be easily transformed in simple linear model by getting log of both sides of the formula **y = a*b^x**. And wikipedia says that TSS = ESS + RSS is true for simple linear regression. At least that is how I see it.

Comment: I don't know how to help you unfortunately.  I doubled checked your fits with using `np.polyfit(x, y, 1)` and np.polyfit(x, np.log(y), 1) and I get the same answer for you linear case and also for your Logarithmic case (note I get the same `a,b` not the same `A,B` for your Log case).  If TSS = ESS + RSS then it looks like you are calculating your coefficients correctly, which means there must be something wrong in the way you are calculating the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a term that is zero when you're using linear regression, since you're not, you have to add it. In the link that Vince commented, you can see that TSS = ESS + RSS + 2*sum((y - yhat)*(yhat - ybar)).

You need to include that extra term in order for it to add up:

```py
extra_term = 2 * np.sum((y - Exponential_Prediction_y) * (Exponential_Prediction_y - y.mean())) 
print(str(TSS) + " = " + str(ESS_Exp) + " + " + str(RSS_Exp) + " + " + str(extra_term))
```

Comment: That is right, thanks. I did not calculate the extra term for linear model, and the equation still worked. So, I decided it was not really needed. It was a mistake. It is needed for exponential model.